# div to fill the height of parent

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to fill the height remaining of the parent with black color.

I put a div with class **fill-black** in this page :

http://diary.applyss.me/blouses/2-7-chemisier.html#/1-taille-s/11-couleur-noir

In the center column, I put the div just below the text ***Détails du produit***

I tried to use some flex properties, I want this div to fill the height of the parent. Is is possible using only CSS ?

I tried :

```
.fill-black {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
    align-items: stretch;
    background: #000;
}
```

Here is a visual of what I want : http://b3.ms/6x1nzg1rMDQG

I put height to 200px, but I want this height to be responsive.

Comment: Can you add a bit more context to the question? I dont really want to have to guess your markup.

Comment: I added a screenshot of I would like to do http://b3.ms/6x1nzg1rMDQG